# sql-server, IF statement within SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble with using an `IF` statement within this sql-server query.

What I want:

If `salesHeader.[Ship-to Name]` isn't null, I need to return that AS DeliveryName, if it is null, return something else.

Is there a way to do this with an `if` statement in a query?

```
SELECT
   poHeader.No_ AS PONumber, 
   poHeader.[Buy-from Vendor No_] AS VendorNumber, 
   poHeader.[Document Date] AS DocDate, 
   salesHeader.GiftMessage, 
   salesHeader.[Delivery Comment] AS DeliveryComment,                     
   salesHeader.[Shipment Date] AS DeliveryDate, 
   IF salesHeader.[Ship-to Name] IS NOT NULL 
      salesHeader.[Ship-to Name] AS DeliveryName
   ELSE
      poHeader.[Ship-to Name] AS DeliveryName
   END 
FROM         
    dbo.[Crocus Live$Purch_ orders for e-mailing] AS poForEmailing 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.[Crocus Live$Purchase Header] AS poHeader ON poForEmailing.No_ = poHeader.No_ 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.[Crocus Live$Vendor] AS vendor ON poHeader.[Buy-from Vendor No_] = vendor.No_ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.[Crocus Live$Sales Header] AS salesHeader ON salesHeader.No_ = dbo.fnGetSalesOrderNumber(poHeader.No_)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Or use COALESCE...

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(salesHeader.[Ship-to Name], poHeader.[Ship-to Name]) AS DeliveryName
```

COALESCE will return the first non-NULL value in the list

Answer (score 11):

Use CASE, not IF

```
CASE 
    WHEN salesHeader.[Ship-to Name] IS NOT NULL THEN salesHeader.[Ship-to Name]
    ELSE poHeader.[Ship-to Name]
END AS DeliveryName
```

Edit:

Both COALESCE and ISNULL answers give in other answers are equally valid too for this particular case (and simpler, frankly)

Answer (score 5):

You can use CASE:

```
(CASE WHEN cond-1 THEN value-if-1
      WHEN cond-2 THEN value-if-2
      ELSE default-value END) AS column-name
```

Or in this situation you can use COALESCE or ISNULL:

```
COALESCE(salesHeader.[Ship-to Name], poHeader.[Ship-to Name]) AS DeliveryName

ISNULL(salesHeader.[Ship-to Name], poHeader.[Ship-to Name]) AS DeliveryName
```

Answer (score 2):

As what gbn said, use CASE statement instead.

Since he has already done the coding, so I don't want to place the same thing again.

Instead just giving you some site to refer for your understanding

a) 
[SQL SERVER – CASE Statement/Expression Examples and Explanation](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/14/sql-server-case-statementexpression-examples-and-explanation/)

b) [CASE function in SQL Server 2005 - part I](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3666131/CASE-function-in-SQL-Server-2005----part-I.htm)

c) [CASE function in SQL Server 2005 - part II](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3666141/CASE-function-in-SQL-Server-2005---part-II.htm)

d) [CASE Function in SQL Server 2005 - part III](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3670611/CASE-Function-in-SQL-Server-2005---part-III.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but don't you have to put the 'AS DeliveryName' **outside** the IF?

At least that's how it works in MySQL...